# Recovery and Shrink

Tags: sql-server, recovery, shrink

I am trying to change the Recovery Mode from `Full` to `Simple` if the database doesn't have any `Full` or `T.Log` backups setup from past week days.

The problem I am facing with the below script is it's selecting `database name` twice and spitting the code to execute along with data files, butIi need only **log** files to shrink and change the database to `Simple` recovery mode.

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_shrink_log]
--WITH Recompile
--AS
--BEGIN
declare
    @isql varchar(2000),
    @dbname varchar(64),
    @logfile varchar(128);

declare c1 cursor
for
SELECT distinct(D.[name]) AS [database_name]
    ,(Select BS3.Name where BS3.type='1') as Logfile
FROM 
    sys.databases D
LEFT JOIN  
    ( 
    SELECT BS.[database_name],  
    MAX(BS.[backup_finish_date]) AS [last_log_backup_date]  
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset BS  
    WHERE BS.type = 'L'  
    GROUP BY BS.[database_name]  
    ) BS1  
ON D.[name] = BS1.[database_name] 
LEFT JOIN  
    ( 
    SELECT BS.[database_name],  
    MAX(BS.[backup_finish_date]) AS [last_data_backup_date]  
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset BS  
    WHERE BS.type = 'D'  
    GROUP BY BS.[database_name]  
    ) BS2  
ON D.[name] = BS2.[database_name] 
LEFT JOIN 
    ( 
    SELECT NAME,database_id,type
    from sys.master_files MF
    ) BS3
ON D.Database_id=BS3.database_id
WHERE 
        D.[recovery_model_desc] <> 'SIMPLE'
    and D.[name] not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb',
        'ReportServer', 'ReportServerTempDB')
    AND BS1.[last_log_backup_date] IS NULL
    OR  BS1.[last_log_backup_date] < BS2.[last_data_backup_date]
    and BS3.type='1'
ORDER BY D.[name];

open c1;
fetch next from c1 into @dbname, @logfile;

While @@fetch_status <> -1
begin
    select @isql = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @dbname + ' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'

    print @isql
    --exec(@isql)

    select @isql='USE ' + @dbname + ' checkpoint'

    print @isql
    --exec(@isql)

    select @isql='USE ' + @dbname + ' DBCC SHRINKFILE (' + @logfile + ', 1)'
    print @isql
    --exec(@isql)

    fetch next from c1 into @dbname, @logfile
end

close c1;
deallocate c1;
--END
```

Comment: what rdms system are you using?

Comment: Are you changing recovery model from full to simple just so you can shrink transaction logs? [Please read this in full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own code :) how ironic.

Here is the piece need to change (around line 43)

```
SELECT NAME,database_id,type
from  sys.master_files MF
Where type = 1 -- I added this bit!
```

Hope this code helps some one here.

Comment: or line 47 change to `AND (BS1.[last_log_backup_date] IS NULL OR BS1.[last_log_backup_date] < BS2.[last_data_backup_date] )and  BS3.type='1'`

Comment: Also be careful with this type of thing.  You don't want to be changing a database to simple recovery without business buy in.  Instead you should be reporting on databases without backups correctly scheduled and then have the business make a decision as to full/simple recovery and then schedule backups/change to simple based on that decision.  FYI this includes development databases. In that case the "business" is the development team using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much-cleaned-up version without the `WHILE` cursor.

Do **not** run this until you check with the business, to make sure they are happy changing over to `SIMPLE` Recovery Mode!

```
USE [master];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

--ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_shrink_log]
--WITH Recompile
--AS
--BEGIN
    DECLARE @isql VARCHAR(8000);
    SET @isql = '';

    SELECT @isql = @isql + 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(D.[name]) + ' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
USE ' + QUOTENAME(D.[name]) + ';
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC SHRINKFILE (' + QUOTENAME(BS3.[name]) + ', 1);
'
    --SELECT D.[name], BS3.[name]
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.databases
        WHERE [recovery_model_desc] <> 'SIMPLE'
          AND [name] NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb',
            'ReportServer', 'ReportServerTempDB')
        ) D
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT BS.[database_name]
            ,MAX(BS.[backup_finish_date]) AS [last_log_backup_date]
        FROM msdb.dbo.backupset BS
        WHERE BS.[type] = 'L' -- Log Backups
        GROUP BY BS.[database_name]
        ) BS1 ON D.[name] = BS1.[database_name]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT BS.[database_name]
            ,MAX(BS.[backup_finish_date]) AS [last_data_backup_date]
        FROM msdb.dbo.backupset BS
        WHERE BS.[type] = 'D' -- Differential Backups
        GROUP BY BS.[database_name]
        ) BS2 ON D.[name] = BS2.[database_name]
    LEFT JOIN sys.master_files BS3 ON D.Database_id = BS3.database_id
        AND [type] = '1' -- LOG
    WHERE (
            BS1.[last_log_backup_date] IS NULL
            OR
            BS1.[last_log_backup_date] < BS2.[last_data_backup_date]
            )
    ORDER BY D.[name];

    PRINT(@isql);
    --EXEC(@isql);
--END
```

It outputs one of these per row:

```
ALTER DATABASE [My lovely DB] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
USE [My lovely DB];
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC SHRINKFILE ([My lovely Log File], 1);
```

Comment: i get the magic of coding :)